# Can't verify CSRF token authenticity in the production side using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment, csrf

I have a blog application in ruby on rails which is finely working in the development side. But when I try to deploy it into the heroku I am getting the  `Can't verify CSRF token authenticity` and `Completed 401 Unauthorized` error in the heroku log while creating a new post in my application.I also seen many previously asked questions and included `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`. But the error is same. How to resolve it. I have included the git repository for your reference.[git repository of my application](https://github.com/praveen-928/socialnetwork)

Answer (score 1):

Add below line in controller .

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
```

You can need to add action in which problem is coming

`:only/:except` - Only apply forgery protection to a subset of actions.

For example `only: [ :create, :create_all ]`

Comment: In which controller i need to give this

Comment: you need to put it in `posts_controller.rb`.

Comment: controller in which there is problem .

Comment: okay I will try that

Comment: Do i need to add forgery protection for post create alone??

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna okay

Comment: @BodharthLonkar I have given that now i can create a post but when i try to delete a post it is rendering to the post show page.Also the post is not deleted.

Comment: What error its showing in logs ?

Comment: It is not showing any error in log

Comment: I just rendering to the show page.Not only for deleting the post the same is obtained for deleting a topic and comment.

Comment: @BodharthLonkar Whenever I try to delete a topic/post/comment it is redirected to the respective show pages

Comment: @PraveenR can you try below code in `rails c`:  `Post.last.destroy` and let me know what happens.

Comment: @PraveenR You can vote my answer if it works for you. Thanks !

Comment: Should I need to delete it using console

Comment: @BodharthLonkar I used it but in the console it is fine and the post is successfully deleted. whereas in production environment I am facing the same issue

Comment: @PraveenR : Try on production rails console .

Comment: okay I will try

Comment: How to run production console

Comment: @PraveenR : heroku run rails console --sandbox

Comment: @BodharthLonkar Now it is deleted successfully in console

Comment: this doesn't resolve issue, this make application vulnerable.

Comment: But when I delete a post it is redirecting to the show page how to resolve it @Зелёный

Comment: @Зелёный Also the question is different from that you have mentioned